# Encountering a 403 Forbidden Error When Attempting to Access Virtual Host Configuration on a Windows Server

Tags: apache, xampp

Encountering a 403 Forbidden Error When Attempting to Access Virtual Host Configuration on a Windows Server

I'm configuring a virtual host for my Angular application, but I keep encountering a 403 error. The provided configuration is aimed at directing incoming requests to the server, yet it's not functioning as intended.

## error

> AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/xampp/httpdocs

## Configuration

`
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/httpdocs"
ServerName 192.168.0.32

```
Alias "/rtsis-fe" "C:/xampp/httpdocs/rtis-fe/dist/rtsis-fe"

<Directory "C:/xampp/httpdocs/rtis-fe/dist/rtsis-fe">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog "logs/rtsis-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/rtsis-access.log" common

RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite all requests to index.html to enable Angular routing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /rtsis-fe/index.html [L]
```

`

Answer (score 0):

In Xampp, the default document root (configured in httpd.conf) is "htdocs", not "httpdocs". Also, the standard IP used by Xampp is 127.0.0.1, not 192.168.0.32. Besides, your vhost configuration is unnecessarily complex. Edit the original C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf, adding the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\rtis-fe\dist\rtsis-fe"
    ServerName rtsis
    ErrorLog "logs/rtsis-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/rtsis-access.log" common
    # Rewrite all requests to index.html to enable Angular routing
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} != '/index.html' ">
        RedirectMatch "/.*" "http://rtsis/index.html"
    </If>
</VirtualHost>
```

As you are using other name than localhost for you server (rtsis), this name must be included in the file C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. Add the following line to it:

```
127.0.0.1   rtsis
```

Now, access you web page typing http://rtsis.

Note: I assume that you have the document root folder structure implemented, and an index.html file inside it. After this basic test, put any file or folder beside you index.html file, and try to request them (it will be possible only if you comment the Redirect code inside the httpd-vhosts.conf file and restart Apache afterward).

By the way: you received a 403 (Forbidden), probably because the httpd.conf file in Xampp is configured to enable requests in the htdocs folder, and not in the "httpdocs" folder!

References:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html